# Limit horizontal depth (qty of outlinks discovered by page) in stormcrawler

Tags: stormcrawler

I am using stormcrawler and I am wondering if there is anyway to limit qty of outlinks discovered by page. I am looking something like `db.max.outlinks.per.page`  in Nutch. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment but this could easily be added to [JSoupParserBolt](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/bolt/JSoupParserBolt.java#L342) and maybe the Tika equivalent. Feel free to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: thanks Julien! I can do that too, I will try to add a PR... we have been having troubles with huge crazy sites that contains millions of pages

Comment: that would be great. BTW are you listed on https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Powered-By?